# Decodable for Dictionaries in JSON - Swift

Tags: json, dictionary, decodable

I am trying to use `Decodable` for `Dictionaries` in `JSON` data, but I get these errors: 1) Type 'Customer' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' and 2) Use of undeclared type 'Address'. Any help would be great.

```
struct Customer : Decodable {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var address : Address
}

struct CustomersResponse : Decodable {
    var customers : [Customer]
}

let json = """

{
    "customers":[
        {
            "firstName" : "Henry",
            "lastName" : "Collins",
            "address" : {
                "street" : "1200 Highland Ave",
                "city" : "Houston",
                "state" : "TX",
                "geo" : {
                    "latitude" : 29.76,
                    "longitude" : -95.36
                }
            }
        }

    ]

}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

let customersResponse = try! 
JSONDecoder().decode(CustomersResponse.self, from: json)
print(customersResponse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `address` and `geo` `Dictionaries` are considered **Nested Objects**. You are getting the **Type 'Customer' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'** Error because of the **Use of undeclared type 'Address'** Error. So first, you need to eliminate that second error by declaring the `Address` type. But, then you will get two new errors if you don't declare `Geo`, as well. Add the following code to the top of your project to eliminate any errors and produce the proper output.

```
struct Geo : Decodable {
    var latitude : Double
    var longitude : Double
}


struct Address : Decodable {
    var street : String
    var city : String
    var state : String
    var geo : Geo
}
```